# Conditional Probability Example to Make the Point Obvious

Tags: probability

My son asked me a standard conditional probability question that came up in his exam: Box 1: (4, 5, 7 ,9); Box 2: (1, 2, 3, 5); Box 3: (13 , 14 , 15 ,16, 17, 18); Box 4: (8, 9, 10, 11, 12). A box is drawn at random, and then a card at random. Given that the card is even-numbered, what is the probability that it is from Box 3?

In his answer, my son reasoned that there are 8 even-number labeled cards, Box 3 contains three of them, thus the answer is 3/8. I drew a probability tree and explained why it is 5/16. He agreed with my logic but did not understand what was wrong with his. I said that his answer would be the case had all the cards been put together in a box, drawn one at random, announced as even, and asked the probability that the card is originally from Box 3. He agreed with that also, but I sensed that he was not fully convinced why his initial reasoning was wrong. So I decided to come up with an example (perhaps with the ratios exaggerated) that would make the point obvious but couldn't think of one. What would be an obvious example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct probability is
$$
\frac{P(E\mid B_3)}{\sum_j P(E\mid B_j) }\tag1
$$
while your son is calculating
$$
\frac{n_3P(E\mid B_3)}{\sum_jn_j P(E\mid B_j) }
=\frac{P(E\mid B_3)}{\sum_j(n_j/n_3) P(E\mid B_j) },
\tag2
$$
where $E$ denotes "card drawn was even", and $B_j$ is the event "Box $j$ was selected", and $n_j$ is the number of cards in box $j$. To make (1) and (2) as different as possible, you have to exaggerate the ratios between $n_3$ and the other $n_j$'s. So try a situation where all boxes consist of half even cards, but boxes 1,2,4 have only two cards, while box 3 has a billion cards. Approach (1) gives the answer $1/4$, while approach (2) gives an answer pretty close to $1$.

You can simplify the situation by having only two boxes in total.